# Connect to database using dependency injection

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, database-connection, simple-injector

I am trying to learn how to use dependency injection, but I have some trouble when it comes to my database. This is my process so far:

I have an MVC project where the controllers use different repositories from my classlibrary.
All repositories use the same database.

At first, I used SimpleInjector to register the Repositories Application_start method:

```
var container = new Container();
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();
var client = new GraphClient(uri, username, password);
container.Register<IRepoA>(() => new RepoA(client);
container.Register<IRepoB>(() => new RepoB(client);
container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
container.Verify();

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
```

And in every method, I did like this:

```
  client.Connect();
  client.performSomeQuery();
  client.Dispose();
```

This works, but it means that I am reconnecting to the database every single time I call a method.
To avoid this a moved the connect-call to here:

```
var container = new Container();
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();
var client = new GraphClient(uri, username, password);
client.Connect();
container.Register<IRepoA>(() => new RepoA(client);
container.Register<IRepoB>(() => new RepoB(client);
container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
container.Verify();
```

But then I never get my connection disposed.

I thought now is to register my databaseclient;

```
container.RegisterSingleton(() =>
{
    var client = new GraphClient(uri, username, password);
    client.Connect();
    return client;
});
```

And then inject it like this:

```
container.Register<IRepoA>(() => new RepoA(container.GetInstance<GraphClient>()));
```

Is this the correct way to do it?

Is it corretly understood that the connection will get disposed by the end of the containers lifetime?

I do get a "Implicitly captured closure: container" when I register the client.

Comment: Creating a new connection per request would be the normal approach.  Think about it - a web application may have to service many tens or hundreds of requests simultaneously.  You don't want these things to all be vying for the same actual connection object.

Comment: I had just read this and thought it was to expensive to call @GPW

"You should only have one instance of it for each database that you want to talk to (typically, one) 
This avoids excess calls to the Connect() method which requires a roundtrip to the neo4j server"

[link](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/connecting)

Is it enough to call connect in each method (as I did first) 
or should I create a new client object in each method

using (var client = new GraphClient(_uri, _username, _password) )
{
    client.Connect();
    client.Query();
    client.Dispose();
}

Comment: I see, I didn't realise you were using a specific library which is thread-safe and suggests a singleton approach.    Is there a reason why you are registering the classes with Lambdas?  I would expect you should only need to register the classes and their implementations with DI - it should actually create them for you (so you wouldn't need to specify how to create an IRepoA and would therefore avoid the closure warning)

Answer (score 1):

there is more than one way to do things ... so asking for THE correct way might get you on the wrong path sometimes ...

but here is what i'd do in your case ...

i would introduce a pattern called unit-of-work ... think of it as a business transaction

you open a unit of work and within its lifetime you perform various DB interactions, possibly all within one database transaction. All those interactions may spread across different repositories. if your whole batch of interactions is done without errors that would require a rollback, you declare the unit of work complete and leave its scope (scope as in a using(...) scope)

if there is an error you do not declare it complete before its lifetime ends ...

on the end of lifetime of your unit of work, you can either commit or roll back all underlaying db transactions (usually it's only one) depending on the fact if complete was declared or not

this unit of work object usually also holds my db connection object(s) and provides connections to repositories

again with dependency injection, you can have factory methods that provide different db connections based on the interface the repository requests during instantiation ...

usually the first repo that needs a connection causes the factory to create one and open it (optionally you can have different connections based on the used repos) while the second repo that asks for a connection gets a connection that has been created and opened before ...

the end of the unit of work (see IDisposable) also means the end of the connectionfactory ... end of connectionfactory means the end of open connections and repos ... since the later are instantiated insied of a using block, and based on the used resource, they should never leave said block